# C# How to use a 'foreach' statement using a data source?

Tags: c#, winforms, foreach, listbox, datasource

Hi guys I've made a owner drawn list box which adds avatar and the users friends name and email.I'm having a little trouble. Basically I have a query which gets the users friends names and email and then the query is added to a list box data source by using 'query.ToList()'. What I'm trying to do is for every friend in the data source, I want it so that it creates a new list box item.

Code:

```
        FriendsLb.DisplayMember = "Display";
        FriendsLb.ValueMember = "FirstName";
        FriendsLb.ValueMember = "LastName";
        FriendsLb.ValueMember = "Email";

        var query = from o in Globals.DB.Friends
                    where o.UserEmail == Properties.Settings.Default.Email
                    select new
                    {
                        FirstName = o.FirstName,
                        LastName = o.LastName,
                        Email = o.Email,

                        Display = string.Format(" {0} {1} - ({2})", o.FirstName, o.LastName, o.Email),
                    };

        FriendsLb.DataSource = query.ToList();

        foreach (object contact in FriendsLb.DataSource))
        {
            FriendsLb.Items.Add(new Contacts(Properties.Resources.avatar, contact.ToString()));
        }
```

Error:
[image: Error]
Any ideas? Cheers

This is what it should look like when the code is correct:

[image: Gui]

Comment: You dont add items to controls bound to a DataSource; Doest `Contact` include the info you collect for the query/DS?

Comment: Did you add the `if (e.index > -1)` in your DrawItem event from your last deleted post?

Comment: No it doesn't, Contact only gets the avatar and friend details and returns them

Comment: You can only have one ValueMember.

Comment: Based on the questions you are posting, a DataGridView would be a more appropriate control to use instead of a ListBox.

Answer (score 0):

You should rather create a DTO or a viewmodel then and use it rather like

```
public class Contact
{
  public string Firstname {get; set;}
  public string Lastname{get; set;}
  public string Email {get; set;}
  public string Display {get; set;}
}

    var query = from o in Globals.DB.Friends
                where o.UserEmail == Properties.Settings.Default.Email
                select new Contact
                {
                    FirstName = o.FirstName,
                    LastName = o.LastName,
                    Email = o.Email,

                    Display = string.Format(" {0} {1} - ({2})", o.FirstName, o.LastName, o.Email),
                };
```

Add the datasource to your databound control like below. Again, as already commented, you can have only one `ValueMember` and not multiple.

```
    FriendsLb.DataSource = query.ToList();
    FriendsLb.DisplayMember = "Display";
    FriendsLb.ValueMember = "Email";
```

Comment: Thanks! How would I use the 'foreach' statement to add every friend to the list box?

Comment: @richardj97, you don't actually. see edit in answer if that helps.